# On what basis do you flag/vote to close a cross posted question?

Tags: discussion, cross-posting

How do I flag/vote to close a question which is already asked by the OP on an other SE website ([example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43830902/bruteforce-with-hashcat-how-to-set-the-mask-properly))?

By *how* I refer to *on which basis/criteria*?

I think I can flag it with '*in need of moderator intervention*' but I think that is something to avoid in general.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Cross-posting the same questions on multiple sites, [is forbidden on Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/64068/is-cross-posting-a-question-on-multiple-stack-exchange-sites-permitted-if-the-qu).

The usual way to resolve this is to flag using the other option and mention clearly<sup>1</sup>:

> This post is cross-posted on <Stack Exchange site name>: <link to post>

But make sure that the post is more on-topic on the other site and not the other way around.

Usually, once flagged, moderators will take a look at the post and delete it. However in many cases, the post would have a good answer which would be lost if the post was deleted. In those cases, moderators will migrate the post to the other site and speak to the other site’s moderators asking them for a merge.

---

<sup>1</sup>  <sub>Be quite clear in the flag that it's a cross post, in one case a user had flagged as "duplicate on the other site <link>" which was *wrongly* declined with the reason "moderators can't close posts as cross site duplicates"</sub>