# Custom flags for cross-posted questions don't seem to get through

Tags: discussion, cross-posting, custom-flags

In the last week or so, I have raised 4-5 custom flags for questions [cross-posted](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/64068/is-cross-posting-a-question-on-multiple-stack-exchange-sites-permitted-if-the-qu) verbatim to other SE sites.

Save for one, all these other flags seem to be perpetually pending - neither accepted nor declined.

Given that:

- This is the [standard way](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/348959/on-what-basis-do-you-flag-vote-to-close-a-cross-posted-question) for handling cross-postings, which I have been following consistently in the past, with the vast majority of these past flags deemed helpful
- Such "delays" seem not to be the case for other kinds of flags I have been raising (mainly NAA & comment ones)

I wonder if this solely due to moderator workload, or if there has been some change in the suggested way of handling such content which I have potentially missed.

In the latter case, I would appreciate a notice, so that I stop wasting time raising such flags.

**Update** (Apr 26): ~ 20hrs after posting this, all pending flags have now been processed (and found helpful).

Comment: I would imagine these flags can take longer to handle, since the decision has to be made about which question to preserve (if any). This may require communicating with mods in other sites. And we have less moderators than we used to have. I had custom flags pending for almost two weeks before they were handled, so I wouldn't describe unhandled flags raised "in the last week or so" as "perpetually pending".

Comment: we're short on mods. The only real answer to this is that you'll have to wait. (or, you know, try pushing for a new election so we can get more mods again and cut down the mod flag queue, but that's probably a fight none of us can win)

Comment: @Zoe thanks but, BTW, have I missed some thread or something revealing this mod shortage? Have not seen explicitly any resign announcement thread or something lately, apart from random references in the comments of irrelevant threads (arguably not the best way to communicate staff).

Comment: We've [had at least 5 mods step down](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/moderator-resignation?tab=Newest). At least one has come back, and at least one resigned without a post on that specific tag. There's no single post saying it's a problem, but when the result of the past two-three elections have been canceled out by resignations, it has an impact.

Comment: Ah, looks like we're at a net of 5. Compare [this](https://web.archive.org/web/20190417152450/https://stackoverflow.com/users?tab=moderators)  (note: might take a while to load - archive.org is misbehaving. Snapshot from a while after the most recent election) to [the current list](https://stackoverflow.com/users?tab=moderators), which means [we're back down to the same mod count as we were before the 2018 election](https://stackoverflow.com/election/).

Comment: The pure count is also not representative of activity; there's a lot happening that we mortals can't see. There's also mods who are more active than others, and some who aren't as active for various individual reasons. My point is, as I already said though, fewer mods indirectly means longer handling time on flags. While that sucks, there's nothing we can do about it, unfortunately.

Comment: @Zoe I could have imagined something like that, if it wasn't for the 2nd bullet though; seems to affect disproportionately the custom flags?

Comment: Well, the main difference with NAA flags is that regular users can handle it. Same with comment flags, but there's no review queue (but 3 flags on a +0 comment nukes it, mod or no mod). Another factor is that mod flags tend to be harder to deal with, and some of them require actual investigation beyond looking at the post and seeing the problem. This especially applies to plagiarism flags, or flags involving bad reviews, etc. With NAA flags, it either is or it isn't, and it's easy and fast to notice. Also, some mods focus on different aspects, or just happen to be in the right place when neede

Comment: With NAA flags, there's one notable exception, and that is if the answer is upvoted, and/or accepted. That makes it get appended to a/the mod queue, at which point, in which case, it does take longer to handle the flag.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I'm not aware of any change of how they are to be handled so don't worry about that and feel free to keep flagging as you see fit. However I would point out they're not flags that need action now. As @Zoe points out in comments, certain things get handled faster (or also handled by the community anyway), and the "other" queue is always a little trickier because they generally require a fair bit of research and consideration that other more obvious flags don't always need. So, in summary, they'll get handled - don't worry about that - but for now - they're going to be low priority amongst others.

Comment: Thanks. All pending flags have now been processed and found helpful; it does raise a thought that the post may have acted as a kind of wake-up call, but no worries I guess....