# Why was my cross-posting flag declined?

Tags: discussion, declined-flags, cross-posting, custom-flags

I flagged [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63413128/identifying-anomalies-in-spatial-latitude-longitude-time-data) (now deleted by the OP) for being cross-posted verbatim to Data Science SE; the exact text of my custom flag was:

> Cross-posted to Data Science SE (where it arguably belongs): https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/80280/identifying-anomalies-in-spatial-latitude-longitude-time-data

The post had an answer that was practically a link-only one; and my flag was

> declined - If it's off-topic here, just close it. Quote rules in the comments for their benefit

Given that:

- This has been the [standard way](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/348959/on-what-basis-do-you-flag-vote-to-close-a-cross-posted-question) for handling cross-postings, which I have been following consistently in the past, with the vast majority of these past flags deemed helpful
- We were recently (April 2020) [reassured](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/396952/4685471) that this is still the standard way of handling such posts, and nothing has changed in the meanwhile

I wonder why my flag was declined with the given justification, and if this signifies some change in the rules which we should be aware of.

I perfectly understand that, given that the question was eventually closed with a negative score, thus entering the roomba queue, the flag may have seemed redundant, but arguably this cannot be a reason for declining (plus that negative scores can always change, and link-only answers can be accepted).

Comment: New modz; give 'em a break. :-)

Comment: @CodyGray NO MERCY! :p

Answer (score 96, accepted):

I probably should have handled that one differently in hindsight. We get a lot of flags asking moderators to close things that are closable by the community, which we tend to decline to encourage non-diamond users to use their tools (flags and close votes) for instead. But looking at it again I could have tossed a diamond closure here. One of those nuanced things I'm still trying to get the hang of.

Apologies if I created any confusion there.

Comment: Hey, first complain about a new mod.  (that I know of)

Comment: All good and no worries. Truth is, there is no close reason for cross-posting, and mods usually end up deleting such posts instead of just closing them, as Bhargav points out in the linked post.

Comment: @Braiam - my first day or so into the diamond mod role all those years ago and I got thwacked: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/92521/419   :)

Comment: Sorry. I was one of the people who asked a moderator to close :D

Comment: I think it's funny that this complaint was close related, given the platform you ran on

Comment: @desertnaut (1/2) I'd say there is a huge reason for cross-posting: Often questions blow in the wind unanswered for all eternity on one network, when on a related network you can reliably get an answer within a day or two. I'll never feel guilty for taking advantage of that knowledge, downvotes and closed questions be damned. The pedantic nature of this site is off the chart, and often well intended rules serve no other purpose except to boost the egos of those who have enough little colored circles to wield power.

Comment: (2/2) For this reason, I post in the most relevant network first and wait a while. If nothing pops, I might try a different network. Again, I will not apologize or stop doing that. Now, you've attempted to help me on more than one question I had, and on more than one network (I think). For that, I am very grateful. However, I have to respectfully disagree with your reasoning.

Comment: @rocksNwaves it is not my own reasoning, it's a [community guideline](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/64068/is-cross-posting-a-question-on-multiple-stack-exchange-sites-permitted-if-the-qu).